# I am getting a 8024402C error on Windows Update

Tags: windows, update

I have a Window Server 2008 Standard Edition. When I try to do the updates I get the error "Code 8024402C Windows Update encountered an unknown error." Most of the help I can find about this error says that you should clear out your proxy setting on the computer and stop and start windows update. I don't have any proxy setting to clear, but I have stopped and started windows update, but I am still getting this error.

I am kind of stumped what to try next.

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: Have you logged in with another account that has local administrative privileges?

Comment: Yes. I just tried this. I did a complete reboot and logged in with another admin account, but I got the same results. The 8024402C error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the windows updates to work by clicking a link button in Windows Update dialog "Check for updates managed by your system administrator". I had to do that a couple of times. I kept getting different errors until the "normal" Windows Update started to work, but everything seems to be working now.

Answer (score 2):

My windows 2008 server was giving error 8024402c. I did two things and it started working:

1) IE > Advanced > Restore advanced settings and Reset.
2) stop and start update services.

Thanks